# I accidently deleted the default Edit permission at site level

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-experience, team-sites, office-365-groups

I accidently deleted the default Edit permission at site level.

Who can help me?

Comment: Do you mean that you removed Microsoft 365 group from "Members" group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have removed permissions of Microsoft 365 group from Site Members group (Edit permissions), you can again add permissions to Microsoft 365 group from site settings.

Follow below steps:

1. Click on Settings (gear icon)
2. Select Site permissions
3. Scroll at the bottom side of right panel and select "Advanced permissions settings"
4. Open SharePoint default "Members" group (it will have name in format: `<Site name> Members`)
5. Click on "New" --> Add users to this group
6. Search & select name of your Microsoft 365 group
7. Click Share

Comment: Could you please explain to me step by step. I really would appreciatie it

Comment: So when i go to the site settings can i then make a new group and add the permissions. Is that the right way?

Comment: I don't think i am authorise to perform these steps because I can not find the settings "Advanced permissions settings"

Comment: What permissions you have on this site? You can directly go to the advanced permissions settings using URL like: `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_layouts/user.aspx` and then follow from step 5.

Answer (score 2):

By default the edit permission level cannot be deleted via UI. It cannot be selected to modify. How do you delete it？
[image]
Anyway you can create a new permission level with the same permission settings.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I ment Team Site Members [EDIT]

Comment: Can someone help me I accidently deleted the default Team Site Members [Edit]

Comment: @user2170776, site level or library level? Reply from Genesh will be the solution for you. For M365 group connected sites, just re-grant permission to the groups